# Use compile LaTeX to HTML with subfiles

Tags: html, pandoc, subfiles, latex2html

I've got a rather large tex project I'd like to turn into one or many linked html files. However neither of my go-to converters, pandoc and latex2html, seem to support recursive compilation.

Is there a compiler flag for one of them that I'm missing? If not, is there a converter that supports what I'm trying to do, or do I just have to copy and paste everything into one absurdly long document?

EDIT:

To be clear, I have a file `main.tex` with the `subfiles` package. I have several other files, `i.tex` etc, of the form:

```
\documentclass[/path/to/files]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Some words
\end{document}
```

How do I include all of them in my final document, either as content in some `main.html` or separate `i.html` files linked in to `main.html`, without doing the hard work by hand?

Comment: do you include the subfiles in the main document, or is each of them separate document with it's own preamble?

Comment: So I'm using the actual subfiles package. Each one is its own document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tex4ht` support this. It needs a simple configuration file, `subfiles.4ht` to support multiple subfiles:

```
\def\:tempa#1{%
  \ifcsname subfiles@end\endcsname
  \else
    \subfiles@saveEndTo\subfiles@end
  \fi
  \let\choose:begin\@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\def\csname end \endcsname##1{%
    \romannumeral
    \subfiles@StrIfEqTF{##1}{document}{%
      \z@
      \subfiles@restoreEndFrom\subfiles@end
      #1%
    }{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\z@\subfiles@end{##1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\HLet\subfiles@renewEndDocument\:tempa
\Hinput{subfiles}
\endinput
```

It disables `\end{document}` in the included subfile, because it would close the document otherwise.

Simple example.

Main file `sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{Subfile example}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\subfile{subfile1.tex}
\end{document}
```

Included file `subfile1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[sample.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}
Some words

Příliš žluťoučký kůň
\end{document}
```

You can compile the document using command

```
make4ht -u sample.tex
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: This works for me when I use only one subfile. I can't seem to get this to work with more than one subfile, or even anything at all after the `\subfile` command in `sample.tex`.

Comment: @frabjous thanks for the report, it seems so.

Comment: @frabjous I've added a `subfiles.4ht` file, it should fix this issue.

Comment: Seems to work so far. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Does latexml do what you want? I'm a little unsure of your exact needs but it can take a large LaTeX file and split it up by chapter or section (etc) into multiple HTML files.

I'm no expert but the command I'm using to do this (assuming document `tex/mydocument.tex` and saving to an `html/` directory) is:

```
latexml tex/mydocument.tex | latexmlpost - \
  --sourcedirectory=tex \
  --format=html5 \
  --destination=html/mydocument.html \
  --splitat=chapter \
  --splitnaming=label
```

Here the split is by chapter, and each chapter needs a `\label` for the split naming to work. If you remove `--splitnaming=label`, it will simply call each HTML file something like `Ch1.html`..`ChN.html`.

It's not included in TeX Live but I had no problem on macOS installing directly from the [LaTeXML Github repository](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML).

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite of that---take several tex files and make them one html file.

Comment: Hmm, your question didn't say that. I assumed "subfiles" was just a descriptor, not a package :) I think I would either preprocess or recreate the .tex sub-files without the `\documentclass` and `document` environment lines, and use plain old `\input` in a master document that can be fed into latexml (or other, if they supposed that too). It would be possible to define appropriate behaviour in `latexml` so this isn't necessary but I haven't figured out how to do that yet.